# Two textures scale difrrent on retina iPad

Tags: unity-game-engine, retina

I'm having a problem with that code:

```
rect = new Rect(saveTextures[0].width, saveTextures[0].height, saveTextures[1].width, saveTextures[1].height);
GUI.DrawTexture(rect, saveTextures[0]); 
if(GUI.Button(rect, saveTextures[1]){
    //do stuff
}
```

It should look exactly the same, and it does in editor. It also looks totaly the same on iPad2, but on iPad3 the top GUI.Button is scaled down to approximatly 90%.

Any ideas what could be the problem?

I make a simple example of the problem. Here is how it should look and looks on iPad2. [image: Example on normal screen]

And here is how it looks on retina screen:
[image: retina screen]

The red part is the button, and it covers whole background on first but only like 90% on second.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the texture type to GUI and that its max size is high enough (try 4096 if not sure).

Also noticed that your Rect constructor is a bit strange. It's `new Rect(top, left, width, height)`, so you're using `saveTextures[0]` as top-left and `saveTextures[1]` as width-height while displaying them in the same position.

Comment: SaveTextures[0] and saveTextures[1] are the same size, so no diffrence which one do I use. It's max size is ok also. However texture type is sprite. Could that be a problem? Seems a bit weird for me...

Comment: I haven't used non-legacy 4.5 uGUI sprites yet, but as you're using this in the classic GUI system, I suggest using the legacy GUI texture mode.

Also, is a screenshot possible?

Comment: I added example screens.

Comment: Pardon my scepticism, but the screens look a bit fake... Please Debug.Log the height/width/top/left values of the Rect and width/height of both textures on ipad2 and ipad3. Maybe that will say something about the issue